# How to interpret the connections from celery worker parent process?

Tags: python, celery, psutil

I started a celery queue with a concurrency of 2:

celery worker -c 2

When I was trying to check the connections by using `psutil`, it returns 13 connections from the parent PID of the celery worker ([Python Celery - lookup task by pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444015/python-celery-lookup-task-by-pid)):

```
[pconn(fd=25, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40826), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=20, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40812), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=21, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40818), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=19, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40814), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=23, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40820), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=26, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40828), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=24, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40824), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=27, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40830), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=3, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40810), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=30, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40832), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=31, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40834), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 pconn(fd=22, family=2, type=1, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 40816), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6391), status='ESTABLISHED')]
```

Questions are: why there are 13 connections since I only requested for 2 celery workers? How to interpret each parameters? How to use these parameters to check the running status of celery workers?